# How do I preserve a copy of my $scope variable in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you can view this [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/pJwsYHQBSG6mUqyCx1KP?p=preview), you know my exact problem. I am unable to keep an old copy of my scope variable.

Below is my code.

```
$scope.init = function() {
  var data = [{
    id: 1,
    d: 'mon',
    sel: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    d: 'fri',
    sel: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    d: 'fri',
    sel: false
  }, {
    id: 4,
    d: 'sun',
    sel: false
  }];

  $scope.myData = data;
  $scope.oldMyData = data;


  angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(value, key) {
    if(value.d == 'sun'){
      value.sel = true;
    }
  }, $scope.myData);
```

Here the `oldMyData` is also getting updated. How do I preserve a copy of the old data ?

p.s : I am not using jquery.

Comment: mr downvoter care to comment ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var original;
original = angular.copy($scope.myData);

$rootScope.original = angular.copy($scope.myData); // this original variable can access inside your angular app
```

dont forget to inject $rootScope to the controller

you have the the old values in `var original` :)

Comment: I want to preserve the old values through the app i.e it should be in the scope so that i can access it whenever I need it